# How can Realm be used with a Rails app & and iOS app platform product?

Tags: realm

If Realm is a replacement for SQLite how can it be used with a platfrom product that includes a Rails web app and an iOS app? Is Realm suitable for the Rails app, or is there a better option / solution?

Comment: I don't know why this was down voted other than that someone misunderstood the technologies involved.

Answer (score 0):

Realm does not currently have a Ruby binding, so it cannot be used by a Rails app.

Comment: While Realm does not have a Ruby binding (and likely won't), it is not true that it cannot be used with Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible.
Realm can be used with Ruby (and Rails) over GraphQL. You can use any GraphQL library you like to send queries and mutations to either your own Realm server or a hosed one on Realm Platform.
However, as there is (currently) no "ActiveRealm" style adapter it requires writing your own.

Here are the docs on making the requests themselves.
https://docs.realm.io/platform/graphql-web-access